# Installing Eagle on 14.04 x64

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit

I have downloaded the latest version of Eagle 7.2 from this [link](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/).

The software is saved in Desktop. Then I changed the directory to Desktop via terminal and tried to open it by typing `./eagle-lin-7.2.0.run`. Then terminal shows `bash: ./eagle-lin-7.2.0.run: Permission denied`. This is the only method that I know to open these types of software.

I need to run the software. Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the *.run* file executable. This can be achieved using `chmod`.

`chmod +x filename.run`

The above command gives executable rights to *filename.run*

In your case - `chmod +x eagle-lin-7.2.0.run`

Now, you can execute it using either `./eagle-lin-7.2.0.run` or `sh eagle-lin-7.2.0.run`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the pc board design program, please use the following instructions.  If you refer to some other program named eagle, please ignore this answer and please do not downvote my answer for trying to help you.

1. Press your windows key.
2. Type SOFT and then press enter.
3. Type eagle.
4. When eagle appears in the list shown, select that and press INSTALL.
5. Enter your password when prompted.
6. Wait while your software is properly installed.
7. Upvote my functional answer.

(Repeat of last night's rant:  Why does anyone bother to install a beautiful, highly functional GUI linux like Ubuntu and then insist on using the command line to perform mundane functions?)